# Office 2010 Add-in deployment

Tags: c#, deployment, ms-office, add-in, visio

I'm searching the way in order to properly deploy a Visio 2010 Add-in.
I tried to publish it via ClickOnce, and it does the job. But I would like to have just one file, in Setup.exe style.
So I oped for a Setup Project, unfortunately with no success. The files are copied, I see it under the Programs list, but the add in is not registered.
Perhaps you know how to check if Visio 2010 is installed during the installation process, if not abort it, and then register the add in?
Any other solution?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deploying/Installing an outlook addin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172970/deploying-installing-an-outlook-addin)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a long research I found this guide that explains everything, step by step and has an working example! Well done Microsoft!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937654.aspx

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In order to deploy the addin you have to

- Create entry in registry form
  installer in
  HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office... (manifest, loadBehavior, friendlyname, culuture etc)
- Attach to the installed files .VSTO
  and .manifest file
- Add VSTO runtime and proper .NET version to the pre-requisites

Comment: Any link on how to achieve this?
I was thinking on adding the keys in registry form installer for HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Visio\Addins\Visio.ForwardEngineer but then I need to add a key like this Manifest"="file:///C:/.../Visio.ForwardEngineer.vsto and I do not know what to specify in vale of the key

Comment: I think it may give you a hints: 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/haahmadi/archive/2010/05/26/my-vsto-add-in-does-not-load.aspx

Anyway it depends what type of installer do you use? Is it visual studio installer?

PS: i'll advise you to use HKCU, not HKLM, bcoz HKLM requires some patch in office which is not installed on every pc

Comment: The faster method is to recompile project as release, run it and then use this two files in installetion. Then point it in registry. If you are using visualStudio use IE:

[TARGETDIR]Visio.ForwardEngineer.vsto|vstolocal

Comment: I am trying to figure out what I need to register in order to make it work properly, and which files I need to include. I was following this guide http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/bb496949 but I think that things are changed since the newer versions are made and this is for Visio 2010. Any open source example somewhere?

Comment: The registry entries are explained : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx