# File, eMail Filing for End User Add-in 2010 v3.0.dll.config, has a different computed hash than specified in manifest

Tags: c#, window, installation, vsto

I have a problem in using installer for creating out look plug in. Even though I can install, the files insides the program file did not go well and add in also does not load in outlook.

When I press, vsto file in program, the following error pop up.

> System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: File, eMail Filing for End User Add-in 2010 v3.0.dll.config, has a different computed hash than specified in manifest.
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.DownloadAddIn(TimeSpan timeout)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()

Could any one can help me please?

Comment: [Deploying/Installing an outlook addin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172970/deploying-installing-an-outlook-addin) - You may want to check this thread solutions to make sure your Outlook Addin is correctly installed.