# Deploying Outlook Plugin C#

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins

I developed an outlook plugin using C# and Visual studio Outlook addin template, that retrieves data from databases and generates a report off of the data.

Plugin works perfectly fine on my local machine. But when I distribute the plugin as an executable to the users, it does not work on the user's machine.
Meaning the addin is not checked by default and even if I check it manually, it does not show up on outlook in the addin bar.

I am unable to figure out if its due to the certificates or anything else.Do I need to install any certificates on the users machine ?

Could some one please help me out ?

- EDIT

  I right click on the solution file in solution explorer and publish to a folder to generate the setup.exe . My other team mate uses the same steps with the same project checked out of perforce and publishes a setup.exe. Now, his plugin works as expected on the user's machine and mine doesnot work (mine works only on my machine). So, I am not able to figure out what the difference is. Because we both are using the same framework (4.0) and VS (VS 2010 premium).It has something to do with the my machine. not sure if I am missing any installation

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deploying/Installing an outlook addin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9172970/deploying-installing-an-outlook-addin)

Comment: Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff937654.aspx) out.

Comment: as it is a possible duplicate I have added my answer in the link Avantol13 posted

Answer (score 0):

Hope the following steps will help you solve this problem. I assume you are using Outlook 2013 or 2010.

- Run the deployed setup with administration rights.
- If it is not shown under Add-ins, again open the setup folder and double click on the correct .vsto file then select install.
- If you can see your add-in among others, and is not functioning, it means your add-in is disabled. To enable it go to `File -> Slow and Disabled Add-ins`, and you should see your add-in on the pop-upped window. Enable it.

Edit:

If your plug-in is shown in Disabled Add-ins try applying the following steps:

- Enable your plug-in by `File -> Slow and Disabled Add-ins`, and you should see your add-in on the pop-upped window. Enable it.
- Right click on your add-in bar and select `Customize the Ribbon`.
- Then on the pop-upped window, choose `All Commands` from the left hand side combo box. You should be able to find your command in the list box.
- When you find your command click on the `Add` button between the lists. This will add your command to the chosen category on the right hand-side list. Then click `OK`.

Your command should appear under the chosen tab.

Comment: Tried this already but did not work. It disables the add in after the outlook start up and say even if I enable the add in, add in is not shown up.

Comment: @user2569524 can you please check if you are able to implement the new solution of mine ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a chance to check out the Trust Center settings on the problematic PC? Are the VBA macro settings applied to COM add-ins? Is the Office application configured to load only signed add-ins?

Microsoft Office applications can disable add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your add-in, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when an add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the Startup event handler in your add-in is executing.

Soft disabling can occur when an add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable an add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the Startup event handler is executing.

When you re-enable a soft-disabled add-in, the application immediately attempts to load the add-in. If the problem that initially caused the application to soft disable the add-in has not been fixed, the application will soft disable the add-in again.

Read more about that in the [How to: Re-enable an Add-in That Has Been Disabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268871.aspx) article.

Also you may find the [Troubleshooting COM Add-In load failures](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2008/04/22/troubleshooting-com-add-in-load-failures.aspx) article helpful.

Answer (score 0):

How are you deploying the add-in? You need to be sure you have configured the installations settings so when you execute the installer MS Outlook knows were to find it and all of its installations components.

In my example I am using MS Project, Visual Studio 2012 with Install Shield.

Below is an example of the registry settings I use for my add-in. You will notice I have configured the manifest to point to installation directory and points to vstolocal.

You will also need to add your .vsto file to your build when constructing the installer.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I right click on the solution file in solution explorer and publish to a folder to generate the setup.exe . My other team mate uses the same steps with the same project checkedout of perforce and publishes a setup.exe. Now, his plugin works as expected on user's machine and mine doesnot work (mine works only on my machine). So, I am not able to figure out what the difference is. Because we both are using the same framework (4.0) and VS (VS 2010 premium).It has something to do with the my machine. not sure if I am missing any installation.

Comment: If you are using VS 2010 I assume you are deploying this via the 'Setup Project' component bundled with VS 2010? Have you tried taking a copy of your teammates Setup Project, loading it into your project and try building it from his and see if it works or it you can find the missing piece?

Comment: I am not adding a separate setup project (template on other project types on VS) to my solution/project file. I right click on the solution file and choose publish from the options and it creates a setup for me.My team mate is following the same procedure to publish.